# Mapped drive error message - mapped drive is full

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, disk-space-utilization

I have a Windows 2003 domain, and one of my clients gets a `mapped drive Z: is full` message when mapping a drive on the server.  The drive on the server is not full.

My understanding is that the issue can be related to quotas.

If the user has used up their own quota, is he/she prone to getting the above message?

And how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

go through this link

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-2003/Configuring-Disk-Quotas-Windows-2003.html

it may help you

Comment: If you provides solution from external resources, please quote the most relevant part of an important link in your answer. See http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer